# matplotlib subplot gridspec automatic axis limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to create a subplot using matplotlib using gridspec.
I was wondering why matplotlib isn't putting correct x limits on the plot.

x values are a range from 0 to 40, but the plot only shows 1 datapoint, as the plottet x axis only reaches from -0.06 to 0.06.

Do I have to set the xlim manually when using subplot + gridspec?

```
x = range(0, len(stuff["training"]))
y = stuff["training"]

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1], sharex=ax1)

plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp([ax1, ax2], title='Test')

ax1.scatter(x, stuff["training"])
ax2.plot(x, stuff["lr"])

fig.suptitle('An overall title', size=20)
gs.tight_layout(fig, rect=[0, 0, 1, 0.97])
```

[image: it looks like this]

EDIT: I think I found the problem
This is not working:

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1], sharex=ax1)
ax1.scatter(x,y)
```

This is working:

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2])
ax1.scatter(x,y)    
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1], sharex=ax1)
```

Comment: Can you give as a reproducable example? A sample data frame `stuff` that we can use to reproduce this issue?

Comment: x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

Comment: `stuff = pd.DataFrame({"training" : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "lr": [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]})` gives a perfectly fine plot here.